# Custom horizontal scroll with animate.css

Tags: html, css, animate.css, mcustomscrollbar, wow.js

I have some code:

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 // Horizontal scroll
    if($(".js-page-scroll").length){
        $(".js-page-scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
         axis:"x",
            theme:"dark-3",
            // scrollbarPosition: 'outside',
            advanced:{ autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true },

            callbacks:{
                    whileScrolling:function(){
                     
                     new WOW().init();
                        
                    }
                }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.js-page-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>  

  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="js-page-scroll">
    <main>
      <section>
        <h2>1</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>3</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInLeft">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>4</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>5</h2>
        <p class="wow bounceIn">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
```

I use custom scroll (horizontal) - [malihu custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

For animation - animate.css and [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

The problem is that with the horizontal scroll, the text in the blocks appeared (animated) smoothly and, consequently, sequentially (as when using wow.js).

**Question:** how to configure wow.js (or, perhaps, what is another plugin) for a horizontal scroll? `or` How to configure animate.css for a custom scroll (when scrolling blocks appear smoothly, sequentially)?

Comment: I might recommend using [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/) instead of WOW, as it seems to be more configurable and can handle horizontal scroll (see [here](http://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/going_horizontal.html))

Comment: @zgood, I tried and scrollmagic, but I need the class to remain on the back scroll. That is, I can not remove toggle (.setClassToggle ... setClass - there is no such property)

Comment: sorry for my english

Comment: @zgood I tend to avoid ScrollMagic as it doesn't play well with mobile devices.

Comment: I think you have changed your requirement recently is it so?. I have seen all the tabs has the same animation but now it differs from others.

Comment: I have updated the code as per the new changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your snippet, the issue is you have initiated the WOW plugin on the scrolling. That's why the animation for all paragraph tag is triggered simultaneously.

From your snippet, I have added custom code instead of using **WOW Plugin.**
While scrolling I have called custom function added by me `animateContent();`

### JS CODE

```
// Custome code for smooth animation 

                  function animateContent() {

                   var divWidth = $(".js-page-scroll").width();
                   var divWidthLg = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 20;
                   var divWidthMd = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 40;
                   var divWidthSm = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 100;
                        //console.log(divWidth);
                         //console.log(divWidthLg);console.log(divWidthMd);


                    var section =$("section");


                     section.each(function(){


                     var offset = $(this).offset().left;
                     var ind = $(this).index() + 1;

                    // console.log(ind, offset);

                     if(offset > divWidth) {
                         $("p" , this).addClass("animated fadeOutUp");

                      }

                     if ( (offset < divWidthLg)){

                     if ($("p" , this).hasClass("fadeOutUp")){
                     $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeOutUp");
                     $("p" , this).addClass("animated fadeInUp");
                     setTimeout(function(){
                     $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeInUp");
                     }, 1500);
                     }
                     else {
                     $("p" , this).addClass("animated fadeInUp");
                     }

                     }

                     if(offset < divWidthSm) {
                      // $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeOutUp");
                       // $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeInUp");
                     }

                     });

                }
```

**What I have done:**

- At first, I have found the total width of the outer `div`
- Then next to it I have found the offset position of each `section`
- If the offset position is less then the total width of outer div and the right offset position, I added  `animated fadeInUp` class thats it.

### DEMO

```js
$(window).load(function(){
 // Horizontal scroll
    if($(".js-page-scroll").length){
        $(".js-page-scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
         axis:"x",
            theme:"dark-3",
            // scrollbarPosition: 'outside',
            advanced:{ autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true },

            callbacks:{
                    whileScrolling:function(){
                     animateContent();
                     
                        
                    }
                }
        });
    }
});


// Custome code for smooth animation 
 
                  function animateContent() {
                
              
                
                   var divWidth = $(".js-page-scroll").width();
                   var divWidthLg = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 20;
                   var divWidthMd = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 40;
                   var divWidthSm = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 100;
                        //console.log(divWidth);
                         //console.log(divWidthLg);console.log(divWidthMd);
                         
                         
                    var section =$("section");
                          
                          
                     section.each(function(){
                     
                 
                     var offset = $(this).offset().left;
                     var ind = $(this).index() + 1;
                     
                    // console.log(ind, offset);
                     
                     if(offset > divWidthLg) {
                     
           $("p" , this).addClass("animated fadeOutUp");
                      
                      }
                      
                     if ( (offset < divWidthLg)){
                     
                     if ($("p" , this).hasClass("fadeOutUp")){
                     $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeOutUp");
                     $("p" , this).addClass("animated fadeInUp");
                     setTimeout(function(){
                     $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeInUp");
                     }, 1500);
                     }
                     else {
                     $("p" , this).addClass("animated fadeInUp");
                     }
                     
                     }
                     
                     if(offset < divWidthSm) {
                      // $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeOutUp");
                       // $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeInUp");
                     }
                     
                     });

                            
                
                
                
                }
```

```css
main {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.js-page-scroll {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>  

  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="js-page-scroll">
    <main>
      <section>
        <h2>1</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>3</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>4</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h2>5</h2>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Here is the demo in [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/swasatz/srjvx51z/16/)

---

### UPDATE  (Seperate animation for each element)

Here I have attached the [Fiddle demo link.](http://jsfiddle.net/swasatz/srjvx51z/18/)

**What I have done here:**
I just get the animation **IN** and **OUT** class form `data attribute`, and append the required animation when it necessary.

By this you can handle **IN** and **OUT** animation for each section.

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
     // Horizontal scroll
        if($(".js-page-scroll").length){
            $(".js-page-scroll").mCustomScrollbar({
             axis:"x",
                theme:"dark-3",
                // scrollbarPosition: 'outside',
                advanced:{ autoExpandHorizontalScroll:true },

                callbacks:{
                        whileScrolling:function(){
                     animateContent();
                        }
                    }
            });
        }
    });
                // new WOW().init();
                
                function animateContent() {
                
              
                
                   var divWidth = $(".js-page-scroll").width();
                   var divWidthLg = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 20;
                   var divWidthMd = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 40;
                   var divWidthSm = $(".js-page-scroll").width() - 100;
                        //console.log(divWidth);
                         //console.log(divWidthLg);console.log(divWidthMd);
                         
                         
                    var section =$("section");
                          
                          
                     section.each(function(){
                     
                    var inAnimation = $("p" , this).data("inanimation");
                     var outAnimation = $("p" , this).data("outanimation");
                     var offset = $(this).offset().left;
                     var ind = $(this).index() + 1;
                     
       // console.log(ind, offset, inAnimation, outAnimation);
                     
                     if(offset > divWidthLg) {
                     
           $("p" , this).addClass("animated "+ outAnimation);
                      
                      }
                      
          if ( (offset < divWidthLg)){
                     
                     if ($("p" , this).hasClass("animated")){
                     $("p" , this).removeClass();
                     $("p" , this).addClass("animated "+ inAnimation);
                     
                     setTimeout(function(){
                     $("p" , this).css("background", "red");
                     }, 1500);
                     
                     }
                     
                     else {
                     $("p" , this).addClass("animated " + inAnimation);
                     }
                     
                     }
                               if ( (offset < 0)){
                                          $("p" , this).addClass("animate "+ outAnimation);
                                             setTimeout(function(){
                                           $("p" , this).removeClass();
                                             }, 1500);
                                        }
                     if(offset < divWidthSm) {
                      // $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeOutUp");
                       // $("p" , this).removeClass("fadeInUp");
                     }
                     
                     });

                            
                
                
                
                }
```

```css
main {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    section {
        display: block;
        width: 300px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .js-page-scroll {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>  

  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
  
        <div class="js-page-scroll">
        <main>
          <section>
            <h2>1</h2>
            <p class="wow" data-inanimation="fadeInUp" data-outanimation="fadeOutUp" data-inanimationn="dsfsdg">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
            </p>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h2>2</h2>
            <p class="wow" data-inanimation="fadeInUp" data-outanimation="fadeOutUp">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
            </p>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h2>3</h2>
            <p class="wow" data-inanimation="fadeInLeft" data-outanimation="fadeOutLeft">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
            </p>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h2>4</h2>
            <p class="wow" data-inanimation="fadeInUp" data-outanimation="fadeOutUp">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
            </p>
          </section>
          <section>
            <h2>5</h2>
            <p class="wow" data-inanimation="bounceIn" data-outanimation="bounceOut">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
            </p>
          </section>
        </main>
      </div>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal scroll detection can be achieved with some simple JS without the need for additional libraries. You are using JQuery so this is one possible solution utilising it.

I used Gemini custom scollbar as it's quite light and user friendly.

I have also included an offset so you can decide when to show the animations rather than firing them off as soon as the element is in view.

---

**Check it out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zfd2t31h/1/**

---

**JS**

```
// Add custom scrollbar
var myScrollbar = new GeminiScrollbar({
  element: document.querySelector('.js-page-scroll')
}).create();

// Add scroll events
var scrollContainer = $('.gm-scroll-view');
var scrollElem = $('section');
var offset = 300;

scrollContainer.scroll(function() {
  var $thisContainer = $(this);

  $thisContainer.find(scrollElem).each(function(n) {
    var $thisElem = $(this);

    if ($thisElem.position().left + $thisElem.width() > 0 && $thisElem.position().left < $thisContainer.width() - offset) {
      $('p', $thisElem).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar@1.5.3/index.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gemini-scrollbar@1.5.3/gemini-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="js-page-scroll">
  <main>
    <section>
      <h2>1</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>2</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>3</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>4</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>5</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima dolorum cumque fugiat ducimus rem dicta sequi neque laudantium, facilis explicabo?
      </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

section {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 1 0 300px;
}

section p {
  opacity: 0;
}

.gm-scrollbar .thumb {
  background: darkblue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work when I scroll the mouse wheel

Comment: Hmm this is a separate issue to that requested and is not the default supported behaviour in most browsers, however you can use a plugin or some JS to resolve this. Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700927/horizontal-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-in-a-div  or use a plugin such as: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/