# How to scroll horizontal linearly from right to left on mouse wheel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

I have more than 6 articles and First I have to display 3 articles and when the user scrolls the mouse wheel than it linearly scrolls from right to left side.
Even I also want to hide the scrollbar.

Would you help me out in this?

I tried code but the same issue. Please check it.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.hScroll = function (amount) {
        amount = amount || 120;
        $(this).bind("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel", function (event) {
            var oEvent = event.originalEvent, 
                direction = oEvent.detail ? oEvent.detail * -amount : oEvent.wheelDelta, 
                position = $(this).scrollLeft();
            position += direction > 0 ? -amount : amount;
            $(this).scrollLeft(position);
            event.preventDefault();
        })
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.full_screen_100').hScroll(60); // You can pass (optionally) scrolling amount
});
```

```css
.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100
{
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
   overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article{
 width: 33%;
 height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;
   display: table-cell;

}
#left_scroll{
 overflow-y: visible;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    clear: both;
    border-spacing: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal_scroll">
  <div class="full_screen_100" id="left_scroll">
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">01</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">02</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
    <article><div><p class="scroll_number">03</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
    <article><div><p class="scroll_number">04</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
    <article><div><p class="scroll_number">05</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
    <article><div><p class="scroll_number">06</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"><
```

Comment: check this question and answer out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700927/horizontal-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-in-a-div

Comment: http://jsbin.com/usabigE/2/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @Stender, I tried that but not working, wait a min I will update it my code again

Comment: @Stender, I updated my code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bp6vswtu/

Comment: @Stender, you change the width from 33% to 16.3%. I need 33% so that I can display the 3 div when page load and after scroll it will be display the linearly. Check your code in full screen. It is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JS

```js
(function() {
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('gentags').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.getElementById('gentags').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
})();
```

```css
#gentags {
position:relative;
margin-top: -.25em;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#gentags > div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:200%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article{
    width: 16.58%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;

}
```

```html
<div id="gentags">
<div class="horizontal_scroll">
  <div class="full_screen_100" id="left_scroll">
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">01</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">02</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">03</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">04</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">05</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">06</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you change the width from 33% to 16.3%. I need 33% so that I can display the 3 div when page is load and after scroll it will be display the linearly.

Comment: And how to remove the scroll bar?

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you will be able to scroll horizontally

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#left_scroll').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta );
     });
    $('#left_scroll').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {//Speacially for Mozilla
      this.scrollLeft += (e.originalEvent.detail*40);//Multiply by 40 because Mozilla DOMMouseScroll speed is 3px at time to match scrolling speed of chrome(speed of scrolling 120px at time)
     });
  });
```

Comment: Is there any other option to use in Mozila