# How to horizontally scroll a table with mouse wheel in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to enable the mouse wheel to scroll the table horizontally.

How can I do it?

CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.container {
  overflow-x: auto;
}


tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

logic code:

```js
function App() {
  const num = 50;
  let points_th = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < num; i++ ) {
    points_th.push(<th>Points</th>);
  }

  let row_1 = render_row('Jill', 'Smith', 50, num);
  let row_2 = render_row('Eva', 'Jackson', 94, num);
  let row_3 = render_row('Adam', 'Johnson', 67, num);
  return (
      <div>
        <div className='container'>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              {points_th}
            </tr>
              {row_1}
              {row_2}
              {row_3}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

here is my demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/Kalipts/scroll_table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [onWheel event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onwheel.asp)

> The `onwheel` event occurs when the mouse wheel is rolled up or down over an element.

With [Element.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo), [Element.scrollLeft](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft)

> The `scrollTo()` method of the Element interface scrolls to a particular set of coordinates inside a given element.

```
element.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

---

Code sample:

```
const onWheel = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const containerScrollPosition = document.getElementById("container").scrollLeft;
  container.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    left: containerScrollPosition + e.deltaY,
    behaviour: "smooth"
  });
};

<div className="container" id="container" onWheel={onWheel}>
```

[image]

Refer: [Horizontal Scrolling on React Component Using Vertical Mouse Wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153797/horizontal-scrolling-on-react-component-using-vertical-mouse-wheel)

Comment: Very good applyable to angular as well. nice example.