# How to scroll vertically after scrolling horizontally

Tags: reactjs, scroll

I have a div that is scrollable horizontally, and I wanted to enable horizontal scrolling with mouse wheel. So I followed what TarVK said in this post: [Horizontal Scrolling on React Component Using Vertical Mouse Wheel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153797/horizontal-scrolling-on-react-component-using-vertical-mouse-wheel).

Now my list is scrollable horizontally, with both trackpad and mouse wheel. Since it still feels a bit off, I'd like to scroll down, once you reach the end of the horizontally scrollable list. And I want this to be possible with both trackpad and mouse wheel. How can I do so?

Comment: as you not sharing the related codes, is there any value or action that changed or called after you rich the end of horizontal list?

Comment: For the code, just refer to TarVK's answer in the post I've linked. There is no action or variable change on reaching the end of the list