# How to implement Internal Scrolling of content in React while scrolling whole page

Tags: html, reactjs, vertical-scrolling

I would like to create a logic in React that scrolls the child content first when scrolling the entire page. Once the child content is fully scrolled, it will then move to the next section

For Example:
I have three sections: A, B, and C. Each section has a height of 100vh. Section B contains four child sections: B1, B2, B3, and B4, all of which also have a height of 100vh.

When scrolling the page, once the scroll reaches section B, its child sections will start scrolling. After the child sections are fully scrolled, the scroll will move on to section C

I have implemented it using GSAP library but I want to implement it using react only.

Answer (score -1):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66687839/13838177). You can create a hook as mentioned in that stack overflow thread and use it.