# Vertical (mouse) scroll on <div> with overflow-x: scroll

Tags: css, sass, scroll, overflow, jsx

I've created a simple post container that allows to scroll trough several card components. However, as the majority of the users are not able to scroll horizontal (with a regular mouse), i need to change the scroll behavior from left -> right to top -> bottom, while the regular overflow-x: scroll is executed. Is there a simple way to implement this *without usage of jquery*?

My code:

```
  .main {
  ...
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  &__feed {
    position: relative;
    height: 70vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;

    &__view {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: scroll;

      &__items {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;

        // CHILD ELEMENTS (CARDS)
        & > * {
          width: 18vw;
          margin-right: $spacing-xs;

          @include media(tab-port) {
            word-break: break-all;
            width: 21rem;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JSX :

```
   <div className='main'>
    <div className='main__feed'>
                <Header title={title} />
                <div className='main__feed__view'>
                  <div className='main__feed__view__items'>
                    {posts && filter === undefined
                      ? posts.map((post) => (
                          <Card
                            title={post.title.rendered}
                            content={post.content.rendered}
                            category={post.categories[0]}
                          />
                        ))
                      : posts
                          .filter((post) => post.categories[0] === filter)
                          .map((post) => (
                            <Card
                              title={post.title.rendered}
                              content={post.content.rendered}
                              category={post.categories[0]}
                            />
                          ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700927/horizontal-scrolling-with-mouse-wheel-in-a-div

Comment: @IvanaG.B. thank you for the fast reply. I've just edit the post that i can't use jquery in this project.

Comment: That is vanilla javascript, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343916/9547423

Comment: Thats right, thank you again. Unfortunately it appears not to work with a regular div. I've used the provided IIFE on the code block above, but without success.